# unsupported content type in afnetworking?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, afnetworking

I am using **AFNetworking** library to send/get data from server.In login api i am sending username & password to server.But sometime i am getting text/html content from server.So to make this work i have used below code but still it is causing the problem.

```
 NSString *url=[BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:LOGIN];
                    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
                    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            self.txt_username.text, @"uname",
                                            self.txt_password.text, @"password", nil];
            AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
            responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript", @"text/html", nil];
            manager.responseSerializer = responseSerializer;
```

Comment: try with AFHTTPRequestOperationManager object to set content type like `manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"text/html",@"application/json", nil];`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [managerObject.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
```

Comment: what is the difference between two of them?

Comment: @TechGuy i don't know but this is working for me. you should also try once. :)

Answer (score 0):

You Can also try this-

```
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = Nil;
```